# Could somebody explaine difference between two queries?

Tags: performance, sql-server-2008, dateadd

The first query is:

```
declare @myDate datetime = DATEADD(D,-2000,getdate())
SELECT * FROM [myTable]  
where CreatedDate >= @myDate
```

The second query is:

```
SELECT * FROM [myTable]  
where CreatedDate >= DATEADD(D,-2000,getdate())
```

I expect that the first query may be faster, because of 'dateadd' function calculates once. But in practice this queries are both equal (2 seconds, 30 000 rows)

Comment: It does not calculate the where DATEADD every row.
It is calculated before the select even begins fetching data.

Comment: Similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7301058/does-sql-server-optimize-dateadd-calculation-in-select-query

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`getdate()` is a [runtime constant function](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/conor_cunningham_msft/archive/2010/04/23/conor-vs-runtime-constant-functions.aspx) and is only evaluated once per function reference which is why

```
SELECT GETDATE()
FROM SomeBigTable
```

will return the same result for all rows regardless of how long the query takes to run.

There is a difference between the two however. As the first one uses a variable and the plan is compiled before the variable is assigned to SQL Server will (in the absence of a recompile) assume that 30% of the rows will be returned. This guess may cause it to use a different plan than the second query.

Something to bear in mind with using `GETDATE()` directly in a filter is that it evaluates `GETDATE()` at compile time and thereafter it is possible for the selectivity to change dramatically without either the query or the data changing to trigger a recompile. In the example below against a 1,000 row table the query using a variable leads to a plan with an estimated 300 rows and a full table scan whereas the query with the function call embedded estimates 1 row and does a bookmark lookup. This is accurate on the first run but on the second run due to the passage of time now all rows qualify and it ends up doing 1,000 such random lookups.

```
USE tempdb;

CREATE TABLE [myTable]
(
CreatedDate datetime,
Filler char(8000) NULL
)

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX ix ON [myTable](CreatedDate)

INSERT INTO [myTable](CreatedDate)
/*Insert 1 row that initially qualifies*/
SELECT DATEADD(D,-2001,getdate())
UNION ALL
/*And 999 rows that don't initially qualify*/
SELECT TOP 999 DATEADD(minute,1, DATEADD(D,-2000,getdate()))
FROM master..spt_values

EXEC('
DECLARE @myDate DATETIME = DATEADD(D,-2000,getdate())
SELECT * 
FROM [myTable]  
WHERE CreatedDate <= @myDate
')

EXEC('
SELECT * 
FROM [myTable]  
WHERE CreatedDate <= DATEADD(D,-2000,getdate())
')

RAISERROR ('Delay',0,1) WITH NOWAIT

WAITFOR DELAY '00:01:01'

EXEC('
DECLARE @myDate DATETIME = DATEADD(D,-2000,getdate())
SELECT * 
FROM [myTable]  
WHERE CreatedDate <= @myDate
')

EXEC('
SELECT * 
FROM [myTable]  
WHERE CreatedDate <= DATEADD(D,-2000,getdate())
')

DROP TABLE [myTable]
```

Comment: does it means that the first variant a little bit long time to execute?

Comment: @Yara - Depends on the selectivity. If the query was highly selective then the second one might consider a plan with key lookups which would be highly unlikely under the 30% assumption.

Comment: Actually if your predicate was using less than (i.e. `where CreatedDate <= DATEADD(D,-2000,getdate())`) then things would be more interesting as the estimated rows affected would be determined at compile time but as time passed the query would get less selective and less optimal. Assuming no changes to the data then no statistics recompile would be triggered to correct this.

Answer (score 1):

SQL isn't going to recalculate DATEADD for every single row. Either way it's going to calculate it once and then run a comparison to the result across your rows of your table. Two different ways, one (perhaps unnecessarily) more verbose than the other, but in the end they give the same result.

Answer (score 0):

The SQL server optimizer is assisting with making the latter query more optimal.

Have a look at the [query plan](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178071%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).